# GKE Autopilot fails to provision GPU node pool

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gpu, artificial-intelligence, google-kubernetes-engine

I have this GKE Autopilot Cluster with a couple of apps (one nodejs app and one python).

At first I requested only CPUs and Ephemeral Storage for both apps (controlled with a Deployment).

But then the python app added some ai model processing requiring a GPU.

I updated the Deployment.yaml of the python app to request a GPU as such:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: <name>
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: <app>
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: <app>
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: <gke-sa>
      nodeSelector:
        cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator: "nvidia-tesla-t4"
        cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator-count: "1"
      containers:
      - name: gpu-pipeline-prod
        image: <docker image>
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
          - name: PORT
            value: "8080"
          ...
        resources:
          limits:
            nvidia.com/gpu: 1
          requests:
            memory: "18Gi"
            cpu: "18"
            ephemeral-storage: "32Gi"
```

But when I apply the Deployment conf to the cluster, the pods are no longer scheduled... They remain in a pending state.

Here is the output of the `describe` command for the pod:

```
Name:           <pod name>
Namespace:      default
Priority:       0
Node:           <none>
Labels:         app=<app>
                pod-template-hash=867bbdf7bb
Annotations:    cloud.google.com/cluster_autoscaler_unhelpable_since: 2023-12-22T15:48:52+0000
                cloud.google.com/cluster_autoscaler_unhelpable_until: Inf
Status:         Pending
IP:             
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/<replica>-867bbdf7bb
Containers:
  gpu-pipeline-prod:
    Image:      <image>
    Port:       8080/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Limits:
      cpu:                4
      ephemeral-storage:  10Gi
      memory:             16Gi
      nvidia.com/gpu:     1
    Requests:
      cpu:                4
      ephemeral-storage:  10Gi
      memory:             16Gi
      nvidia.com/gpu:     1
    Environment:
      PORT:                                 8080
      ...
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-nbx6f (ro)
Readiness Gates:
  Type                                       Status
  cloud.google.com/load-balancer-neg-ready    
Conditions:
  Type                                       Status
  PodScheduled                               False 
  cloud.google.com/load-balancer-neg-ready    
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-nbx6f:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Guaranteed
Node-Selectors:              cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator=nvidia-tesla-t4
                             cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator-count=1
Tolerations:                 cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator=nvidia-tesla-t4:NoSchedule
                             cloud.google.com/machine-family:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             kubernetes.io/arch=amd64:NoSchedule
                             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             nvidia.com/gpu:NoSchedule op=Exists
Events:
  Type     Reason                   Age                From                                   Message
  ----     ------                   ----               ----                                   -------
  Normal   LoadBalancerNegNotReady  19s                neg-readiness-reflector                Waiting for pod to become healthy in at least one of the NEG(s): [<NEG name>]
  Warning  FailedScheduling         16s (x2 over 19s)  gke.io/optimize-utilization-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 2 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling..
  Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp        16s                cluster-autoscaler                     pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added): 18 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector, 1 node(s) had untolerated taint {cloud.google.com/gke-quick-remove: true}
```

The cluster is located in `europe-west1` region.

Seems like autopilot cannot  match nodes with "nvidia-tesla-t4".

How to resolve this?

I followed the tutorial here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/autopilot-gpus

I tried to replace the Deployment conf with a Pod conf (similar to the documentation).

I made sure that I had a GPU quota > 0 for all regions (currently quota is 4).

Comment: I believe you need to remove  `cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator-count`  from the node selector

Comment: I am facing this issue too, any fixes yet ?